# Discord.js Missing Access On Slash Commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

There are other problems like this but none of them have a solution that works for me. I want to use slash commands with my discord bot I have all the scopes including `application.commands` but it still gives me this when I try to execute my code:

```
(node:1648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Access
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\camer\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\camer\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:1648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1648) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: You added the scope before you invited it, right?

Comment: Yes, I did with admin and application.commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was stupid I forgot to put my guild id in quotes!